# Firefox error during three.js execution code

Tags: javascript, firefox, three.js, controls

I try to do a 3D animation with Three.js controls. During the execution of my code in Firefox, a have this error : 
EDIT

SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

And here is my code, simplified :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Three.js Test</title>

        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%;};
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
                <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>

        <script type="module">
                var scene = new THREE.Scene();
                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);


                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                //keep the scene in center of the page
                window.addEventListener('resize', function() {

                    var width = window.innerWidth;
                    var height = window.innerHeight;
                    renderer.setSize(width,height);

                    //prevent distortion
                    camera.aspect = width / height;
                    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                });

                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

                // create the shape
                var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFF0080 } );
                var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( cube );

                camera.position.z = 5;

                function animate()
                {
                    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                    /*cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
                    cube.rotation.z += 0.01;*/

                    renderer.render( scene, camera );
                }
                animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't understand where the error came from and I don't know how to fix it.

I now run my code on a wamp server.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

> import * as THREE from './jsthree.module.js';

It seems there is a typo. It should be `./js/three.module.js`.

In any event, ensure to run your code on a local web server in order to avoid any security issues. More information about this topic in the following guide:

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: Indeed, there was a typo problem.

Comment: You are now mixing in your code module and non-module approaches. If you are not going to use ES6 import statements, you can remove `type="module"` from your `script` tag.

Comment: Yes, but I still have this error : SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Comment: Any chances to share your code as a github repo? In this way, I can try to reproduce the error on my machine.

Comment: Sry, I have no gitlab account^^. Can you please share your code as a public repository?

Comment: It's normally a public repo now. Can you try again ?

Comment: Okay, now it's working. The issue is that you include the ES6 module version of `OrbitControls`. This does only work in a module context. So please use the following version of `OrbitControls` instead: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. I have to use OrbitControls as a function ?

Comment: No, just replace the contents of your current `OrbitControls.js` with the ones from the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196873/discussion-between-missknacki-and-mugen87).